# UIScrollView height while adding content programmatically in UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, height, uistackview

I am trying to make a view containing an `UIScrollView`. This `UIScrollView` contains 3 `UIViews`. The last one contains another `UIStackView` I wanted to fill at runtime.

Here an image of the storyboard :

[image: Storyboard]

[image]

But when I add content at runtime in the second `UIStackView`, the `ScrollView`'s height remains the same.

The second `UIStackView` is defined as the first one with:

- Axis : vertical
- Alignment : Fill
- Distribution : Equal Spacing

Then I use :

```
mStackView.addArrangedSubview(matProgress)
```

The result below :

[image]

What's the way to have the bottom view and the ScrollView stretch to fit the content.

Comment: Do you initially show this with *empty* bottom view? Or when it is first shown it has *some* of the multiple-lines?

Comment: When it first shown it already has some views. The problem I had is described in my comment in the accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The layout *can* be done with auto-layout and constraints.

The key points are:

- do **not** set height constraints on either StackView
- set the "Main" StackView `Distribution` to `Equal Spacing`
- set the "Main" StackView Leading, Trailing, Top and Bottom constraints to its Superview (which is the ScrollView)
- you *do* need to also set a width constraint on the "Main" StackView to control the horizontal contentSize

The only quirk will be on startup. If you have NO content in the bottom / inner StackView, it will still "exist" in the Main StackView and take up space. There is a trick to get around that, but it must be done in code.

You can see a working example here: https://github.com/DonMag/StackyScrolly

Comment: Thanks DonMag, the example you provide helped me to make it work. My project was working exactly as yours when I use `UILabels` as you've done. So the problem was that the views I added in the bottom `UIStackView` haven't got any height constraint...

Answer (score 0):

If you have `UIScrollView` and the child views with auto-layout. Setting programmatically the height of the scrollview will stretch the inside views to comply with the auto-layout.

So, you get by code the height of the third view and set the UIScrollView height to view1.height + view2.height + expectedThirdViewHeight.